# How to convert an IP address from NSString to unsigned int in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, unsigned

How to covert the IP address from **`NSString`** to **`unsigned int`** in Objective-C?

```
NSString A = "192.168.43.149"
```

And I try to convert it to **`unsigned int`** like the following code:

```
unsigned int ip;
ip = (unsigned int)[A intValue];
```

or

```
sscanf([A UTF8String], "%u", &ip);
```

The result always show only **`192`**.

I want it show **`0xc0a82b95`**

How to covert the IP address from **`NSString`** to **`unsigned int`** in Objective-C?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you try to do it to get what ? and unsigned int ip = 19216811 ?
What is the expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IPv4 addresses you can use `inet_aton()`, which converts a string to an Internet
address:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

NSString *addrString = @"192.168.43.149";
struct in_addr addr;
if (inet_aton([addrString UTF8String], &addr) != 0) {
    uint32_t ip = ntohl(addr.s_addr);
    NSLog(@"%08x", ip);
} else {
    NSLog(@"invalid address");
}

// Output: c0a82b95
```